# Update a column and refer back it in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 and need to recursively update a column based on its previous value. For e.g.

```
---------------------------------------
ID |   price   | diff_with_prev_price |
---------------------------------------
1  |   29      | 0                    |
2  |   25      | 0                    |
3  |   20      | 0                    |
4  |   35      | 0                    |
5  |   40      | 0                    |
--------------------------------------|
```

I want to recursively update third column like below

```
---------------------------------------
ID |   price   | diff_with_prev_price |
---------------------------------------
1  |   29      | 0                    |
2  |   25      | 25                   |
3  |   20      | 5                    |
4  |   35      | -30                  |
5  |   40      | 10                   |
--------------------------------------|
```

It is the summation of previous value of third column with next value of 'price'.
Can someone please give some hint to do this either using CTE or LEAD/LAG, but without using cursors. I have to update million rows.

Comment: The output sample you provided seems wrong! Why is the first 1 `0` and the second one `25` ? Why didn't `ID=5` get `-70` ? Seems like the logic changes each one.

Comment: You could use a normal update using "price = price-(whatever calculations)".

Comment: Are you doing a 'reverse recursive'? Otherwise the output makes no sense. Also, what version of SQL server are you using? If 2008 or higher, LEAD/LAG will be your best shot.

Comment: @martennis LEAD/LAG is a SQL 2012 thing, FYI. 2008 would have to use something like an APPLY

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was trying to help out too fast :-)

Comment: This isn't recursive but Lag() will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 1 AS ID , 29 AS price, 0 AS diff_with_prev_prive
INTO #tmp
UNION SELECT 2 AS ID , 25 AS price, 0 AS diff_with_prev_prive
UNION SELECT 3 AS ID , 20 AS price, 0 AS diff_with_prev_prive
UNION SELECT 4 AS ID , 35 AS price, 0 AS diff_with_prev_prive
UNION SELECT 5 AS ID , 40 AS price, 0 AS diff_with_prev_prive

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID
      , price
      , diff_with_prev_prive
      ,  price - ISNULL(LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY ID),0) AS new_value
    FROM #tmp
)
UPDATE t
SET diff_with_prev_prive = t.new_value
FROM cte t

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: I changed the 1st value to 29 but it is just a matter of setting the null value.

Comment: The only issue here is that Windowed functions aren't allowed on update statement. 
But using cte allows you to do so.
an other option would be to use Temp table but I don't see the point specially for performances.